# Updating properties in an Angular service method not reflecting in view

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make the properties inside of a service method dynamic.

In the service I have this method that has a param which needs to change dynamically on the view

```
getSteps(disabledValue) {
   return [
       new StepItem(ReviewQuoteComponent,
       {
         disabled: disabledValue,
       }
   [
}
```

In my service I have created an Observable to watch for changes.

```
  private serviceSteps = new BehaviorSubject(true);
  showServiceSteps = this.serviceSteps.asObservable();
```

Method from within the service to change the values

```
   newStepValues(value: any){
      this.serviceSteps.next(value);
   }
```

Then in the component which loads initially I have:

```
 ngOnInit() {   
    this.stepperService.newStepValues(true);
    this.stepperService.showServiceSteps.subscribe((value) => { 

     this.serviceSteps = this.stepperService.getSteps(value);

});
```

}

Clicking here after load changes the the property to false inside of the object as expected but the view doesn't change?

```
  checkStepsVar(){    
    this.stepperService.newStepValues(false);
    this.stepperService.showServiceSteps.subscribe((value) => { 
      this.serviceSteps = this.stepperService.getSteps(value);
    });
  }
```

I feel like it has something to do with the fact that the updates in getSteps loads on init the view is set and need a way to update the view when data changes in the service method's properties.

---

### **UPDATE!!**

I have been thinking about it the wrong way, So in my service I have:

```
export class StepperService {
  serviceSteps: BehaviorSubject<StepItem[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  showServiceSteps = this.serviceSteps.asObservable();
}

newStepValues(data: any){
   this.serviceSteps.next(data);
}
```

Then in the component that loads data onInit: I get all the data by default and pass this to the method in service and do the subscription.

```
export class StepperComponentComponent implements StepComponent {

  serviceSteps: StepItem[];
 
  constructor(private stepperService: StepperService) { }

  ngOnInit() {  
      //Get data from service method 
      this.serviceSteps = this.stepperService.getSteps();

      //Pass default data into method to update observable 
      this.stepperService.newStepValues(this.serviceSteps);

      //Subscribe to the data returned and set response to serviceSteps 
      this.stepperService.showServiceSteps.subscribe((response) => {
      this.serviceSteps = response;
      // console.log(this.serviceSteps);
    });
  }
```

Then in the components where I want to change properties: I subscribe to data create a new var to hold the changes, target the property I want to change on an event, then set the new value in newStepValues method and finally subscribe to the new value.

```
export class SetUpFuneralPlanComponent implements StepComponent {
  serviceSteps: StepItem[];
  
  constructor(private stepperService: StepperService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      //Subscribe to the data returned and set response to serviceSteps 
      this.stepperService.showServiceSteps.subscribe((response) => {
      this.serviceSteps = response;
    });
  }

  radioButtonClicked(){    
    let newValue = this.serviceSteps;
    for (var i = 0; i < newValue.length; i++) {
      if (newValue[1].data.disabled === true) {
        newValue[1].data.disabled = false;
      }
    }

    //Pass adjusted data into method to update observable 
    this.stepperService.newStepValues(newValue);

    //Subscribe to the data returned and set it to serviceSteps
    this.stepperService.showServiceSteps.subscribe((response) => { 
    this.serviceSteps = response;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should push steps to serviceSteps observable instead of assigning new array to it.

```
this.serviceSteps = this.stepperService.getSteps(value);
```

the above snippet is detaching angular template from the view as it assigned a new reference of array returned by the getSteps.

it should be

```
this.serviceSteps.next(this.stepperService.getSteps(value));
```

But then your type doesn't match with the type declared for the BehaviorSubject that was boolean. Anyway, you should be consistent with types as you're using typescript.

Ideally, it should be an empty array.

```
private serviceSteps = new BehaviorSubject([]);
showServiceSteps = this.serviceSteps.asObservable();
```

also in ngOnInit `this.stepperService.newStepValues(true);`  should be `this.stepperService.newStepValues([]);`

Comment: @A. T. - Would you mind looking at my Update to see if I can do it any better?